# macOS Photos app stops working after editing 1-2 videos

Tags: macos, photos.app, video-editing

I have several mp4 video files that I want to edit (crop, rotate, change aspect ratio, reduce file size) and find that the macOS Photos app can do all. However, the app stops working after editing 1-2 videos. What can I do so that I can edit all the mp4 files? I am using macOS Ventura 13.3.1 on M2 MacBook Air.

(iMovie can do them too, but the exported videos have larger file sizes than the original.)

Comment: Have you waited until the video has finished preparing ("Preparing Video...") before editing other videos? Also, what is the size of the video (data used)? Do you have any other programs/apps running at the same time - what/which programs/apps?

Comment: It did not say "Preparing Video..." when I edited it. The video was about 150MB. Safari and Slack were running.

Comment: It's supposed to be preparing... What do you see instead? Nothing? Try rebooting and upgrading to the latest available macOS version and try again

Comment: I see nothing... My macOS version is the latest.